# case matching strings based on an algorithm. Which algorithm should I use?

Tags: algorithm, scala, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a need to turn TV Ratings (for TV shows) into case object of that rating in my code. Thus I have a case match like so:

```
def fromString(s: String): Option[TvRating] = s.toLowerCase match {
  case "tvy" | "tv-y" | "tv y" | "y" => Some(tvY)
  case "tvg" | "tv-g" | "tv g" | "g" => Some(tvG)
  case "tvpg" | "tv-pg" | "tv pg" | "pg" => Some(tvG)
  case "tv14" | "tv-14" | "tv 14" | "14" => Some(tv14)
  case "tvma" | "tv-ma" | "tv ma" | "ma" => Some(tvMA)
  case _ => Some(noTvRating)
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to match all permutations of each rating, which is cumbersome and still doesn't account for things like "  tv.14", or "mature audiences".

Is there some algorithm like soundX but for code's like these ratings that I could use as a last resort. Then my code will look like this:

```
def fromString(s: String): Option[TvRating] = s.toLowerCase match {
  case "tvy" | "tv-y" | fancyAlgo(s, "tv-y") => Some(tvY)
  case "tvg" | "tv-g" | fancyAlgo(s, "tv-g") => Some(tvG)
  case "tvpg" | "tv-pg" | fancyAlgo(s, "tv-pg") => Some(tvG)
  case "tv14" | "tv-14" | fancyAlgo(s, "tv-14") => Some(tv14)
  case "tvma" | "tv-ma" | fancyAlgo(s, "tv-ma") => Some(tvMA)
  case _ => Some(noTvRating)
}
```

Or any other suggestions where I could make these matching more robust. Since tv-g isn't a word like "dog" or "horse" I can't go based on audio or similar sounding words.

This is one example of ratings. There are also other matches. Here's another example for Star Rating (like Rotten Tomato's Movie Rating)

```
def fromString(s: String): Option[StarRating] = s.toLowerCase match {
  case "1" | "one star" | "one stars" => Some(oneStar)
  case "1.5" | "1.5 stars" | "one and a half stars" => Some(oneAndHalfStar)
  case "2" | "2 stars" | "two stars" => Some(twoStars)
  case "2.5" | "2.5 stars" | "two and a half stars" => Some(twoAndHalfStars)
  case "3" | "3 stars" | "three stars" => Some(threeStars)
  case "3.5" | "3.5 stars" | "three and a half stars" => Some(threeAndHalfStars)
  case "4" | "4 stars" | "four stars" => Some(fourStars)
  case _ => Some(noStars)
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: is Fuzzy string matching what I'm looking for?

Comment: I see what you mean but I think (in general) you're asking for the near impossible - to match anything that means (say) "pg" but without stating the rules for something to mean "pg".  It's not fuzzy string matching because it's not obvious what to match *with*,  If you can give a bit more detail about what can match, say "tv-14" (for instance, should "fourteen" match?) then maybe something can be done

Comment: The whole point of the `Option[]` type is it _might_  be `None`.  Why don't your examples have a `None` condition?

Comment: Good question, I'll check to see if this return value is ending up somewhere. or if any of this style of code anywhere else is using None ever. Some might and for sake of consistency (when putting them in a list, for example, to map) it's better to go with Option here.

Answer (score 2):

Go data driven:

```
val ratings = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]() withDefaultValue "noTVRating"

type TvRating = String

def addRatingStyle(base:String, result:String) = {
  val suffix = base.stripPrefix("tv")
  ratings += ("tv"+suffix->result)
  ratings += ("tv-"+suffix->result)
  ratings += ("tv "+suffix->result)
  ratings += (suffix->result)
}

addRatingStyle("tvy", "tvy")
addRatingStyle("tvg", "tvg")
addRatingStyle("tvpg", "tvpg")
addRatingStyle("tv14", "tv14")
addRatingStyle("tvma", "tvma")


def fromString(s: String): Option[TvRating] = Some(ratings(s.toLowerCase))
```

Comment: upvoted because interesting solution, but does not address my matching problem. The problem is I don't know if the prefix is always "", "-", or " ". Otherwise my original matching just works without adding the above context overload for the programmer. While creative, it doesn't use an algorithm to find a "best" match.

Answer (score 2):

Use `case object`s to define your individual ratings with an `unapply` method.  A simple regex will probably handle the rest:

```
sealed trait TVRating

case object Youth extends TVRating {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[TVRating] = {
    //insert fancier match logic here...
    if( s.matches("tv.*y") || s.equals("y")) {
      Some(Youth)
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}

case object General extends TVRating {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[TVRating] = {
    //insert fancier match logic here...
    if( s.matches("tv.*g")) {
      Some(Youth)
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}

object Main extends App {

  override def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    "tv.y" match {
        case Youth(s) => println("Youth")
        case General(s) => println("General")
        case _ => println("Unknown")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about unapply. That is one cool solution! Only down side I see is that the regex's are not together in one place for me to see or add to them. Question: What's that override doing in front of `def main`?

Comment: This answer illustrates why I commented above that the OP is seeking something almost impossible (it's not an issue with the answer itself, though). Note that General matches PG too. The reason Soundex works is there's a fairly well understood mapping from the spelling of the word to the sound, though the phonetics (although even then due to the usual bizarre English issues there will be many false positive and negatives). And one tends to use Soundex for kind of "good enough" matching not "must sort into exactly the correct bucket" which what is needed here.